# Create a custom element in place where the code was initialized

Tags: javascript, html, element

I'm trying to create an element using JavaScript in place where the script was initialized.

I need to be able to just call a function for the element to appear just after the `<script>` tag in my HTML document.

I tried this code but I don't know how to actually create an element.

```js
function createElement() {

  var container = document.createElement('div');
 container.setAttribute("class", 'someDiv');
 document.createElement(container);
  
}
```

```css
.someDiv {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<body>

<script>
  createElement("div", "someDiv");
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: https://plainjs.com/javascript/manipulation/create-a-dom-element-51/ You need to *put* the element somewhere though, you can't just say "it'll go here after this `<script>` tag". You can use the body, although it's more typical to put it in a div or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.currentScript` seems to have [good browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript#Browser_compatibility), and will give us the `script` element containing the code currently being executed.

If what you'd like to do is **replace the current `script`** with some other element, you use it like this:

```html
<script>
  const replacementText = document.createTextNode("hi, I'm the replacement!");

  document.currentScript.parentNode.replaceChild(replacementText, document.currentScript);
</script>
```

If you simply want to insert an element **after the current script, without replacing it**:

```html
<script>
  const newText = document.createTextNode("hi, I'm new text!");
  const currentScript = document.currentScript;

  currentScript.parentNode.insertBefore(newText, currentScript.nextSibling);
</script>
```

Here's a more complex example using prewritten HTML:

```html
<script>
  const currentScript = document.currentScript;
  
  const templateFragment = (function(){
    const templateEl = document.createElement("template");
    templateEl.innerHTML = `
    <ul>
      <li>Hi!</li>
      <li>I am a list!</li>
    </ul>
    `;
    
    return templateEl.content;
  })();

  currentScript.parentNode.insertBefore(templateFragment, currentScript.nextSibling);
</script>
```

Comment: Your second example would put the new element at the bottom of the parent of the current script, not immediately next to it as a sibling if there are other siblings already present.

Comment: Yes it works but I need to create ANY element like divs or lists...
This method doesn't allow me to do that...

Comment: @ScottMarcus Good catch, fixed.

Comment: @AleksanderCiecierski I've updated my answer with an example of how to inject pre-written HTML. Let me know if that's what you're looking for. Keep in mind that all of this should have been mentioned in your original question in order to help us help you.

Comment: Ok, but what if the script is the last element and there is no sibling?

Comment: It'll still work. If `nextSibling` is `null`, `insertBefore` will [insert the node at the end of the parent element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) and target insertion point as the script like so:

```
var script = document.querySelector('script:last-of-type');
var container = document.createElement('div');

document.body.insertBefore.insertBefore(script, container);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`document.currentScript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript), we can get a reference to the `script` element where the code is running and then using [`.nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling), we can get the next sibling node that is an element. Finally, with [`.insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) and  [`.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild), we can insert the new element just before the element passed in as an argument (the sibling that was found earlier or `body` if none was found).

**NOTE**: Don't call your function `createElement` as it can cause a naming conflict with `document.createElement()`.

This will insert an element just after the `script` element.

```css
.someDiv {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<head>
 <script>
   function create(type, style) {
     var container = document.createElement(type);
     container.classList.add(style);  // Best way to add a class
     container.textContent = "Hello!";

     let sibling = document.currentScript.nextElementSibling;
     if(sibling){
       // Insert the new element before the next sibling
       sibling.parentNode.insertBefore(sibling, container)
     } else {
       // Insert the new element at the end of the body
       document.body.appendChild(container);  
     }
   }
 </script>
</head>
<body>

  <p>The new element should be right below this.</p>
  <script>
    create("div", "someDiv");
  </script>
  <p>The new element should be right above this.</p>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.insertBefore()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) to add some element before the next `sibling` of your `script`. To reference your `script`, you could add an `id` attribute to it:

```css
.someDiv {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>I'm inside the body, before the script TAG</p>
  <p>New element should appear just after this text...</p>
  
  <script id="myScript">
  
    function createElement()
    {
      var container = document.createElement('div');
      container.setAttribute("class", 'someDiv');
      var script = document.getElementById("myScript");
      script.parentNode.insertBefore(container, script.nextSibling);
    }

    createElement();

  </script>

  <p>I'm inside the body, but after the script TAG</p>

</body>
```

Comment: This will always put the new element at the end of the `body`, which is not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yea, sorry, I miss that part, I'm going to update with some alternative.